# Google Cloud Run Second Flask Application - requirements.txt issue

Tags: python-3.x, flask, minikube, google-cloud-run, cloud-run-emulator

I have a google cloud run flask application named "HelloWorld1" already up and running however i need to create a second flask application. I followed the below steps as per documentation:
1- On "Cloud Shell Editor" clicked "<>Cloud Code" --> "New Application" --> "Cloud Run Application Basic Cloud Run Application .."-->"Python (Flask): Cloud Run", provide  and new folder and application is created.

2- When i try to run it using "Run on Cloud Run Emulator" i get the following error:

```
Starting to run the app using configuration 'Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally' from .vscode/launch.json...
To view more detailed logs, go to Output channel : "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally - Detailed"
Dependency check started
Dependency check succeeded
Starting minikube, this may take a while...................................
minikube successfully started
The minikube profile 'cloud-run-dev-internal' has been scheduled to stop automatically after exiting Cloud Code. To disable this on future deployments, set autoStop to false in your launch configuration /home/mian/newapp/.vscode/launch.json
Update initiated
Update failed with error code DEVINIT_REGISTER_BUILD_DEPS
listing files: file pattern [requirements.txt] must match at least one file
Skaffold exited with code 1.
Cleaning up...
Finished clean up.
```

I tried following:

1- tried to create different type of application e.g django instead of flask however always getting the same error
2- tried to give full path of [requirements.txt] in docker settings, no luck.

Please if someone help me understanding why i am not able to run a second cloud run Flask app due to this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your Dockerfile references the 'requirements.txt' file, but that file is not in your local directory. So, it gives the error that it's missing:

listing files: file pattern [requirements.txt] must match at least one file